# document.ready runs even if window.load is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

What to write to check if window is fully loaded then do some functions and if not then do `document.ready` functions....i.e :  i have a preload image which appears if windows isn't fully loaded and i call it in `document.ready`.....and if window is fully loaded i hide this preload image....it runs correctly if window isn't fully loaded and disappear after window get loaded.....but `document.ready` get called even if window is already loaded ...so how to check if window is loaded then don't do `document.ready` and if not then do `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#loding").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("body").css('overflow', 'hidden');
    $("#container").css("opacity", 0);
});
$(window).load(function (e) {
    $("#loding").animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500, function () {
        $("#loding").css("width", "70%");
        $("#loding").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
    $("#container").css("opacity", 1);
    $("body").css('overflow', 'auto');
});
```

Comment: spelling-nazi: it is loading and not loding :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this :

```
var loaded = false;
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   if(!loaded) {
     // only run here if the $(window).load() function hasnt run
   }

});
$(window).load(function(e) {
   // run your functions
   loaded = true;
});
```

uses a simple `boolean` to indicate if the loaded functions have run or not

Comment: But even if this work....when i reload or refresh the page..document.ready runs again...because var loaded is being false again !

Comment: @Booonz the same logic will be applied at each page load

Comment: and your problem being exactly?

Comment: i want to run a certain code in document.ready ( only ) if window.load isn't fully loaded...as i said ( only )..and if window is fully loaded then ignore that code which is in document.ready

Comment: it runs right but only in the first access to page...but it keeps running the same logic in every access by declaring  var loaded = false which i don't want